# jQueryUI Resizable causing position:absolute <li> to not be 100% height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve multiple `<li>` elements inline, each of which is height:100%;

For reasons outside the scope of this question, I desire to NOT have my `<li>` elements positioned absolutely.  Can someone chime in on how to achieve this same layout with `position:relative;` or `position:static;` elements?

Look at my jsfiddle below for reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/kVwRC/7/

Comment: what browser? works in chrome. if it's not "working" in the browser you're using specify `display:block` as height doesn't apply to inline elements...

Comment: They already are positioned absolutely, and the .ui-resizable  from jQueryUI resets this to relative. You can just override that with .ui-resizable { position: absolute; } to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/kVwRC/10/

Comment: My question was how can I achieve this same layout WITHOUT using `position:absolute`